# How can I get python to trigger a process based on an incoming string from serial listening?

Tags: python

Totally new to Python. Working with a Paspberry Pi and Rockblock 2 satellite SBD transceiver connected over FTDI cable. Have managed enough python code to listen to the rockblock to catch a SBDRING trigger. Once received I need it to recognise this so I can try to get it to take an action. My code here fails to trigger and just keeps listening. Is there some rule or reason I've not been able to find as to why the python equalto won't work on what is being listened to?

```py
import time
import serial

port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"

ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=19200, timeout=5)

print "Starting monitor of '" + port + "'"
try:
    ser.isOpen()
    print(port + " is open")
except:
    print("Error")
    exit()

if(ser.isOpen()):
    try:
        while(1):
            print(ser.readline())
            if(ser.readline() == "SBDRING"):
                print "Message detected!"



    except Exception:
        print("Error reading serial")
else:
    print("Cannot open '" + port + "'")
```

Expected result: on display a new line ticks over every 5 seconds. When "SBDRING" appears it should be followed by "Message detected!" and carrying on.

Actual result: on display a new line ticks over every 5 seconds. When "SBDRING" appears it does not displays "Message detected!", just carries on.

I intend to replace the 'print "Message detected!"' part with a actual action once it functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the string you're expecting includes a terminating character like a CR or LF.

You should print what you get from the port and study its length.

Otherwise, you can loosen a bit your comparison, maybe something like:

```
if("SBDRING" in ser.readline()):
    print "Message detected!"
```

**EDIT:** Looking at the [manual](http://www.rock7mobile.com/downloads/RockBLOCK-Developer-Guide-Mk2.pdf), it seems the device terminates everything with `"\r"` so I guess you should manage with:

```
if(ser.readline() == "SBDRING\r"):
    print "Message detected!"
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos. I did attempt `"SDBRING\r"` earlier but this still failed. However I resolved the problem a few hours ago by very similar method to your line of thought so marking your answer correct anyway. I simply changed `if(ser.readline() == "SBDRING"):` to become `if(ser.readline().strip() == "SBDRING"):` and it started working. It seems the device sends some collaboration of `\n` and `\r` both before and after the data wanted. The device docs are good but not always 100% I have discovered.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you're absolutely right, sometimes the documentation is plain misleading. I'm glad to hear you managed to make it work.